# Why the Time part of LocalDateTime changes it's value after persisting it in to database using JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, persistence

```
    //createdAt and lastUpdatedAt are initialised like this:

    LocalDateTime createdAt = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    LocalDateTime lastUpdatedAt = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    
    //Rest of the code...

    System.out.println(rocReviewComment.getCreatedAt().toString() + ">>>" + rocReviewComment.getLastUpdatedAt().toString());
    // Initialize the database
    rocReviewCommentRepository.saveAndFlush(rocReviewComment);
    System.out.println(rocReviewComment.getCreatedAt().toString() + ">>>" + rocReviewComment.getLastUpdatedAt().toString());
```

The first print : 2021-02-22T16:16:14.755>>>2021-02-22T16:16:14.762

---

The second print : 2021-02-22T10:46:44.389>>>2021-02-22T10:46:44.389

You can see that the Time part is changed.

Comment: What database is this?

Comment: I am testing my code. So the database is H2

Comment: Have you tested if you see the same problem with other databases? Basically, have you *researched* to find out if this is a database-specific problem, or a general JPA problem independent of the database? Asked another way, have you done any *research* to try to isolate the source of the problem?

Comment: No, I haven't tested it with another database. But during research, I found something like "JPA store LocalDateTime as BLOB so the database is not aware of the date object and cannot apply any optimization for it."

Comment: JPA can only store it as a BLOB if that is the column's data type. What is the data type of the column? According to the [H2 documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#timestamp_type), `TIMESTAMP` (`WITHOUT TIME ZONE`) maps to `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: LocalDateTime is not suitable for timestamps. Use Instant instead. See http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2018/03/14/dont-use-localdatetime/